# PHP: filter XML by attribute?

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to make some kind of sorting by parameters. I've got XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Name>Logos</Name>
  <Slides>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/22.jpg" lvl="1" designer="0001" theme="outline">Destiption one</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/23.jpg" lvl="1" designer="0002" theme="drawn">Destiption 2</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/24.jpg" lvl="2" designer="0003" theme="outline">Destiption 3</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/26.jpg" lvl="2" designer="0004" theme="drawn">Destiption 4</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/27.jpg" lvl="1" designer="0003" theme="outline">Destiption 5</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/28.jpg" lvl="3" designer="0003" theme="outline">Destiption 6</Item>
  </Slides>
</Root>
```

PHP:

```
$result = $xml->Slides->xpath('Item');//get all items
$search1 = $result[0]->xpath('Item[@lvl="1"]');//failed(((
```

how to search by attribute? The idea is to output all `Item`s with required attr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to the question / title (filter XML by attribute):

You can use [The SimpleXMLElement class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php):

```
// xml example
$foo = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Root>
        <File type="1">File 1</File>
        <File type="2">File 2</File>
        <File type="1">File 3</File>
    </Root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($foo);
// get all 'File' elements with attribute 'type' = '1'
$search1 = $xml->xpath('File[@type="1"]');
//                      ^^^^   ^^
//                   Element   Attribute
```

Then, `$search1` will have files `File 1` and `File 3`.

---

---

*For the OP's specific case:* There is no need to first get all items. You can use it like this, directly:

```
$result = $xml->Slides->xpath('Item[@lvl="1"]'); //get 'Item'-s with 'lvl' '1'
```

so, `print_r($result);` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /upload/portfolio/22.jpg
                    [lvl] => 1
                    [designer] => 0001
                    [theme] => outline
                )

            [0] => Destiption one
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /upload/portfolio/23.jpg
                    [lvl] => 1
                    [designer] => 0002
                    [theme] => drawn
                )

            [0] => Destiption 2
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /upload/portfolio/27.jpg
                    [lvl] => 1
                    [designer] => 0003
                    [theme] => outline
                )

            [0] => Destiption 5
        )

)
```

Note that it returns the urls that end with `22`, `23` and `27` (the ones with `lvl` = `1`)

---

If you take a look at your code, it has `$result[0]->xpath...`. `$result` is already the list of items, so you'd be getting the first item with `$result[0]` (`print_r($result[0]);`):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [file] => /upload/portfolio/22.jpg
            [lvl] => 1
            [designer] => 0001
            [theme] => outline
        )

    [0] => Destiption one
)
```

---

Complete code (Copy/Paste to run):

```
$foo = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Name>Logos</Name>
  <Slides>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/22.jpg" lvl="1" designer="0001" theme="outline">Destiption one</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/23.jpg" lvl="1" designer="0002" theme="drawn">Destiption 2</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/24.jpg" lvl="2" designer="0003" theme="outline">Destiption 3</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/26.jpg" lvl="2" designer="0004" theme="drawn">Destiption 4</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/27.jpg" lvl="1" designer="0003" theme="outline">Destiption 5</Item>
    <Item file="/upload/portfolio/28.jpg" lvl="3" designer="0003" theme="outline">Destiption 6</Item>
  </Slides>
</Root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($foo);
$search1 = $xml->Slides->xpath('Item[@lvl="1"]');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($search1);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you FirstOne! I also found the solution via IF statement in loop but yours is more simple and efficient for server's resources.

Comment: @AndrewBro, Yeah, I though of looping it too, but that `$result[0]` felt a bit weird xD. Anyway, I'm glad to help..

Comment: yep, using $result[0] isn't the best way))